# Sinusoidal voltage on CAN bus signal wires when powered from 3 phase switching power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, can

I am using CAN bus to communicate between this [BLDC motor](https://store.tmotor.com/goods.php?id=1031) with a built in driver and a real-time control computer which uses a galvanically isolated [Microchip MCP2561FDE/SN](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20005167c.pdf) CAN transceiver. Unfortunately I don't have any details on the CAN transceiver built into the motor driver board. Here is a diagram showing the isolation setup for the MCP2561 transceiver.

[image: Block diagram of control computer CAN transceiver galvanic isolation showing that two digital couplers are used to isolate Rx and Tx]

The CAN comms works perfectly when powered with 48V by a [QPX1200SP power supply](https://resources.aimtti.com/datasheets/AIM-QPX_Series_DC_power_supplies_Data_Sheet-Iss2.pdf). CAN high and low sit at the right voltages and dominant states are clear with a differential measurement. Things however get very weird when I try and power the motors with our [48V 10kW power supply](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RST-10000/RST-10000-SPEC.PDF) which is on a 3-phase plug (400V 50Hz). I was getting a ton of passive errors on the bus and because of this messages would only get through intermittently, so I decided to scope the CAN lines and this is what they looked like.

[image: Image of oscilloscope screenshot of 11V peak to peak 104kHz sinusoidal signal on both CAN high and CAN low. The differential measurement is unaffected and stable at 0V]

Sorry for not showing this in the screenshot but the frequency of these is about 104kHz. The 11Vp-p really concerns me. The purple signal is the differential measurement of both probes. When messages come through the differential signal looks fine (sorry I don't have screenshot of this) which is probably why communication is still happening albeit with a lot of passive errors. Even weirder is that when I increased the time scale there was also this 175Hz modulation happening.

[image: Image of 175Hz sinusoidal modulation visible on previous scope signals with time scale increased to 1ms per division]

I immediately tried disconnecting the common ground wire on the motor end and the sinusoidal shape dissapeared but both of the lines still had random signals at 11Vp-p and sometimes even 16Vp-p. After this I turned everything off. I'd really like to provide more scope screenshots I just don't know how much protection is on the motor's CAN transceiver and I can't afford to break one.

I really have no clue what aspect of the power supply could be causing these weird voltages so absolutely any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Check your power supply, that appears to be the source. Also be sure the ground connection is stable and at ground.

Comment: One quick question, did you add 120 ohm resistors at both terminating points or one 60 ohm resistor somewhere on the bus?

Comment: It’s hard to tell what the scope is using for a sample rate, but the modulation could be aliasing.  For running at 50 Hertz you may expect to see modulation at 150 Hz (3rd harmonic), depending on the modulation scheme used by the drive.

Comment: Another note.  The MPC2561 does not say anything about being galvanically isolated.  In the past I have seen circuits use a chip separate to the CAN transceiver for isolation.  Adding isolation will increase the latency (or effectively propagation delay), requiring a lower baud rate.  In my experience, isolation would be needed in any case that devices on the bus do not share a common ground.

Comment: The issue here is that your scope may or may not be misleading you because you are trying to simulate a differential probe with two single ended probes.

When you do that, there is an implication that your *ground* is stable.  Given that you have a strong power supply connected to 3 phase, that may not be true, at all.

Your scope has a ground and it connects to the grounds on the probes.  The point on the circuit that you connect the probes to also has a ground.  Finally, the power supply is likely connected to ground.  You need to be very clear what is connected to what.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Gil yeah it definitely seems to be the source. I just have no idea what part of the power supply. I've tried isolating it with a transformer at the 3-phase plug but that didn't seem to do anything. I'll check the ground and neutral connections today to make sure there isn't some offset voltage.

Comment: @JonathonS. yes I've got a 120Ohm terminating resistor on both ends of the bus, and also double checked that the motor and control computer don't have internal ones. Thanks for the suggestion about the sampling frequency, I'll check that on the scope. I just wouldn't expect disconnecting the common ground to affect that if it were just a sampling issue.

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski that's a good point. The grounding setup I had was both probes connected together, and connected to the motors ground (ground from the power supply). I then also had the motors ground connected to the ground on the isolated CAN transceiver in the control computer for a common reference. I tried my best to have a common reference throughout the system but I'm really not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: @JonathonS. yeah you're right about the MPC2561's isolation. It's got an external isolation circuit, I've added the diagram for this. I just really don't get how it would work perfectly for one supply but not the other. Do you maybe have any idea what that isolated ground shown in the diagram would be for? I'm thinking its as a reference but I'm not sure how that works with the isolation.

Comment: In a case where isolation is used, there must be no connections between the grounds on both sides of the isolation barrier, otherwise this would create a current loop via your CAN lines.  I'm not sure how you've connected the scope to the CAN bus, but you will need to make sure that it's connected between the hollow ground and the lines to monitor.

Comment: Also, it may be good to focus more on the differential voltage on the CAN lines, which is actually what is used for communicating the signal, since this is more tolerant to noise.  I didn't look at the standard, but a quick web search indicates that up to 12 volts line to ground is considered to be acceptable.

Comment: One other thing that I am curious about is, what baud rate are you using?  Your transceiver is designed for 1 Mbit/sec.  However, adding the isolation circuit will actually decrease the overall baud rate capability.  For CAN bus you need to be concerned about the total communication loop delay, including device latencies and propagation delay when selecting baud rate.  Otherwise, the CAN arbitration scheme will not behave properly.